# setting a JTree focused

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a JDialog with a JTree which includes a DefaultMutableTreeNode and its childs. I would like to have one of the nodes of tree focused when the JDialog is displayed. Just use the

```
tree.requestFocus();
```

doesn't seem to work...any ideas?

Comment: what/how are you trying to reach that goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) If you know the row no. you can write tree.setSelectionRow(rownumber)
>   2) If you know the node, then tree.setSelectionPath( new TreePath(node.getPath()) );

-> http://www.coderanch.com/t/332842/GUI/java/JTree-setFocus

Comment: Thanks, it works but...when I press the top and bottom arrows the change of focus to other nodes doesn't happen, same node stays focused, do you know how can I change this?

Comment: Maybe you can use: public void clearSelection() Clears the selection.